# mb_convert_encoding() function is not working in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I am using a library (glocery_crud) in codigniter to convert database table to csv , which is working fine on localhost but on live server it is showing me blank page  and not creating a csv file .

Here is my code -:

```
    // Convert to UTF-16LE and Prepend BOM
    $string_to_export = "\xFF\xFE" .mb_convert_encoding($string_to_export, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
    $filename = "export-".date("Y-m-d_H:i:s").".csv";
    header('Content-type: application/csv;charset=UTF-16LE');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    echo $string_to_export;
    die();
```

if I am commenting first line than i am geting a csv file but not well formatted in csv ()
like -:

```
 testing9988312003sdgsgsdgsgvipul@gmail.comsdgFrayear
```

Comment: 1) if you get blank pages, turn on error reporting and share the error 2) there is no cvs formatting in you code example, so if you receive output without commas, it was probably not in $string_to_export in the first place

Comment: not geting any error , but same code is working fine on local host

Answer (score 0):

it works fine with
        **$string_to_export =  "\xFF\xFE".iconv("UTF-8","UCS-2LE",$string_to_export);**